# How can I get the item in a row of a DevExpress GridControl?

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, devexpress-windows-ui

I want to know how I can assign the value of an item in a row to a variable.

If I double click in any position of the row, I want to assign the value of an item in a row, for example (0, y), to a variable.

Will be grateful if you provide something like that or some alternative.

Awaiting for your reply.

Thanks & regards,
Renato Collado

POSTSCRIPT: I'm working with VB.NET

Comment: Hello and welcome to Stack Overflow.Please take time out for a tour(http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and visit the help center(http://stackoverflow.com/help). You might also want to read How to Ask(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/A2934

Comment: @FloatingKiwi I saw that question but It's too old and already can't be implemented as it is.

Answer (score 2):

Although you tag this with DevExpress-windows-ui you don't specifically state if this is traditional Winforms or WPF.  I don't have much experience using their Winforms controls but I have done a great deal of what you are trying to do with their WPF grids (and I would imagine that the approach to this is broadly similar).

What you should be looking at is the GetCellValue method ([DevExpressMainDocumentation](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WPF/DevExpressXpfGridGridControl_GetCellValuetopic)).

I tend to process my grids from external methods but as an example of the basic syntax;

```
Dim myValue as Boolean
For i As Integer = 0 To grid.VisibleRowCount - 1
    myValue = CBool(grid.GetCellValue(i, "SinglePayment")) 
    'Do stuff with myValue here 
Next
```

You may have to do a little digging around the knowledgebase but you will find numerous examples that illustrate this.

Comment: It was exactly what I needed but it helped me to know where to look. Thank you.

Comment: Renato -- if this answers your question, you should mark it as correct so that others with a similar issue will know that it met your needs